# How to add more than 500 entries to the datastore with put() in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, large-data-volumes, google-cloud-datastore

I tried adding batches of data in a list with a couple of calls to db.put(). But it still timeouts occasionally.

Anyone have some tips?

Comment: I have an xml file with a bunch of contacts that I want to add to the datastore. The Contact model consists of some attributes like phone nr, name etc. I'm currently parsing the xml file into a list of Contact entities and then loading them into the datastore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple puts, and use smaller batch sizes (halving them, for example) if you encounter timeouts. If you're adding 500+ entities in one user request, though, you're probably doing something wrong, though.

Comment: Yeah, writes are VERY expensive with GAE. Perhaps detail exactly what you want to do, and see if we can optimize the process.

Answer (score 0):

The bulkload client that Google provides with App Engine ([bulkload_client source](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/bulkload_client.py)) defaults batch size to 10, so that tells me that you have to very careful about the size of your batches.

I was recently deleting several thousand objects and found that the most I could pass to db.delete() was around 400.  But, sometimes that would timeout and I'd go down to 350. I'm not sure if deletes or puts are more expensive though.